# Python: "ImportError: Cannot import name Celery" with Django, Gunicorn, and Celery

Tags: python, django, celery, gunicorn

I am trying to run Celery using Django 1.7 and Gunicorn 19.3.0. When I run the command to start my Gunicorn server, I get a message that the workers have failed due to the following error:

```
File "/home/saruman/env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
  __import__(module)
File "/home/saruman/env/saruman_server/saruman_server/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
  from .celery_config import app as celery_app
File "/home/saruman/env/saruman_server/saruman_server/celery_config.py", line 5, in <module>
  from celery import Celery
ImportError: cannot import name Celery
```

The command I am using to run Gunicorn is:

```
../bin/gunicorn -c /home/saruman/env/saruman_server/gunicorn_config.py saruman_server.wsgi
```

`gunicorn_config.py` contains:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import multiprocessing

workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1
bind = "127.0.0.1:80"
user = "saruman"
command = '/home/saruman/env/bin/gunicorn'
pythonpath = '/home/saruman/env/saruman_server'
```

Here's a copy of my `__init.py__`:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery_config import app as celery_app
```

And here is my `celery_config.py`:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os

from celery import Celery

from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'saruman_server.settings')

app = Celery('saruman_server')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

I have looked at previous StackOverflow questions, but while those have the same error I do, the solutions in those answers do not help me at all.

Comment: Silly question, but are you sure you have installed Celery? Did you use a virtualenv?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought at first too. I am running it in a virtualenv and I do have Celery installed. I can spawn Celery workers and everything, just not start Gunicorn.

Comment: Is Gunicorn using the same virtualenv?

Comment: Yes, can you show the command/script you're using to start gunicorn?

Comment: @Rawrgulmuffins Yes, everything is on the same virtualenv. And I've just added the command I use to start Gunicorn to the OP.